# Box decoration break overflow

Tags: css, overflow

Having a problem with box-decoration-break and overflowing. Here is a fiddle to illustrate my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/n56226na/3/

```
span {
  display: inline;
  padding: 7px 20px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 40px;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

Basically, I need the text to be boxed, and with padding, according to the design. The problem is on browser resize, the boxes always overflow to the right (and off the page), while the left hand side is padded nicely, due to centre alignment. Here's an image to illustrate my problem:

[image]

In an ideal world, the span would be centre aligned, with a black box white text, but wouldn't overflow it's parent div. Not sure if this is even possible. Appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33096660/text-with-background-color-separated-for-each-row) and after some researches and taking inspiration from others users' suggestions, I found possible solution.

First of all, in [this page](https://css-tricks.com/multi-line-padded-text/) you can find some possible solutions using many different methods.

The best that "**actually**" (browser support varied during time) is to combine the cited "*Fabien Doiron's box-shadow Method*" with a little modification to address only specific behaviour of Firefox 32+.

Your [updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n56226na/8/) has the following specific rule:

```
span {
    display: inline;
    padding: 7px 0;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 40px;
    box-decoration-break: clone;

    box-shadow: 10px 0 0 #000, -10px 0 0 #000;
}
```

I added a multiple `box-shadow` to mimic lateral padding (resetting your original padding declaration).

Anyway, is necessary to add `box-decoration-break: clone;` to override specific Firefox 32+ behaviour that has `box-decoration-break: split;` as default.

Please, note that I left only `box-decoration-break: clone;` because is necessary only for FireFox.

Instead, you (actually) **MUST** remove analogue specifix Chrome variant, `-webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;` because it's the responsible of your unwanted horizontal overflow on window resize.

So, due to fact that Chrome needs vendor prefix for this property, declaring it only with standard syntax is a workaround to make it running correctly even in it and also in IE9+

Answer (score 0):

Add a right margin to the parent the same width as the text's padding (20px in your case). That way it will trigger a line break a little sooner, keeping your text from ever seemingly overflowing.