# Text with background color separated for each row

Tags: css, padding, background-color

I have to add a background-color to a text (a title for example) adding some padding around it.

Applying `display:inline-block` padding is perfect, but obviously, background will span across entire block width (e.g. 100%).

Design requires to have a separate background strip for each line of text, and this could be achieved using `display:inline` with a `line-height:160%;` but this has the drawback of applying padding left only on first row and padding right only on the last.

[Here a jsFiddle with two examples](http://jsfiddle.net/ldetomi/un0eeo9c/). **The second one is the most similar to desired behaviour but obviously padding is not correct**.

Relevant part of CSS code is:

```
.inline-block
{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px 20px;
}

.inline
{
    display:inline;
    padding:5px 20px;
    line-height:160%;
}
```

How to combine advantages of two approaches?

Comment: What is this background strip that you speak of?

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I was not clear, I would like a background bar as in second example (the blue backrgound one), in which background is separated for each row (thanks to to `line-height`) and wide exactly as each row text content (but actually I have problem with padding in this specific situation)

Comment: That's not a background "bar", that's empty space.

Comment: Have you seen my jSfiddle? In post I reported only specific rules of each case not also bacground ones. In jsFiddle, you should see complete example

Comment: If you change the color of your body you should understand. There is no "bar" , text is inlined so the color wraps around the text leaving empty space between each line.

Comment: Yes, it is effectively what I want, and infact is what is visible in second example. The problem is that padding-left is applied only in first row and padding-irght only in the last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking inspiration by other answers that suggested use of `box-decoration:break;` property, I investigated on this topic, finding also [this page](https://css-tricks.com/multi-line-padded-text/) with some possible solutions.

The best that "**actually**" (browser support varied during time) is to combine the cited "*Fabien Doiron's box-shadow Method*" with a little modification to address only specific behaviour of Firefox 32+.

The [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/un0eeo9c/8/) has the following specific rule:

```
.inline
{
    display:inline;
    padding:5px 20px;
    background:blue;
    color:white;
    line-height:160%;

    box-shadow: 10px 0 0 blue, -10px 0 0 blue;
    box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

Multiple `box-shadow` is used in all browsers to mimic lateral padding, while is necessary to add `box-decoration-break: clone;` to override specific Firefox 32+ behaviour that has `box-decoration-break: split;` as default.

---

**NOTE about cross-compatiblity**:

`box-decoration-break: clone;` is necessary only for FireFox.

Rather in Chrome, is (actually) **mandatory** to NOT set equivalent `-webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;` because it adds an unwanted horizontal overflow on window resize. So, due to fact that Chrome needs vendor prefix fro this property, declaring it only with standard syntax is a workaround to make it running correctly even in it and also in IE9+

Answer (score 3):

You can utilize the box-shadow CSS call for this purpose. I have completed a fiddle with end result. You can then play around with it to get the exact result you want

CSS:

```
.highlightme {
background-color: #A8332E;
padding: 0.5rem 0;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1rem 0px 0px #A8332E, -1rem 0px 0px #A8332E;
box-shadow: 1rem 0px 0px #A8332E, -1rem 0px 0px #A8332E;
box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hjardine/un0eeo9c/4/)

Comment: Unfortunately behaviour is not hat I desired. As said, I need separationg between each background row as in my blue bakground example, and also your code is inconsistent across browsers. In firefox has unwanted lateral margins and no padding

Comment: Please see updated JSFiddle, from your comments, it is what you are looking for @LucaDetomi

Comment: what about just add `box-decoration-break: clone;` to his code (the one with blue background), i think it work just fine without adding `span` tag?

Comment: But you would still have to wrap it within a box to make this work

Comment: @HenryVarro Your simple edit to my fiddle would be perfect but unfortunately this specific rule has a [very little cross-compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-decoration-break)

Comment: For this to work you need the Div > h1 (doesnt have to be h1 but something similar) > Span as seen in the JSFiddle

Comment: Have you tried to use it? works fine for me on IE but website says it has "No Compatability"? @LucaDetomi

Comment: Also i created it on Google Chrome which is working completely fine @LucaDetomi

Comment: So as far as I have tested, it works on Chrome, Firefox and IE

Comment: According to the website it has '75.06%' supportage, with IE working this is around '90%', I do not have Edge to test but if IE supports it then I would hazard a guess that Edge probably would

Comment: @hjardine [I tried adding specific vendor prefix for Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/ldetomi/un0eeo9c/5/) and it runs correctly also in this broser with this edit, while in IE (9 I have it on this PC) it does not.

Comment: For IE compatablility `box-shadow:` is required, please the JSFiddle [With IE Compatability](http://jsfiddle.net/un0eeo9c/6/) @LucaDetomi

Comment: @hjardine I tried in Chrome, Firefox and IE9. Unfortunately, you last example, does not work in IE9. I don't know what is the specific rule that is ignored, but surely I know that IE9 does not support `rem` units for example.